# Excel: INDIRECT function cell reference will not drag down

Tags: excel

So i'm working on a spreadsheet where i need to lookup a value from a tab of which the name is defined in a cell, in this case D7. Using this method i can dynamically search my workbook tabs and select the correct tab and cell reference.

The problem i'm having is that the cell i'm retrieving will not change when i drag down the formula.

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$D7&"'!S2")
```

D7 = dynamic tab name

S2 = cell to retrieve... here is where I'm having the problem, this is a value i want to change when i drag down.

Please can someone help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the row of the cell with the formula to calculate the row of the referenced cell:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$D1&"'!A" & ROW())
```

note: the above assumes the formula is in the same row as the cell you are referencing (row 2 in your example)